# Removing the border of uipopover controller in iOS

Tags: uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I would like to create a popover with white color border. I have done by assigning instance of subclass to  popoverBackgroundViewClass. I am able to achieve this with white color (using white image at the background )but with border of the popover is not removed. A white color border Still appears. Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is one crazy solution ) After you presentPopover, you need call this method

> ```
> -(void)removeInnerShadow {
> UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
>
> for (UIView *windowSubView in window.subviews) {
>     if ([NSStringFromClass([windowSubView class]) isEqualToString:@"UIDimmingView"]) {
>         for (UIView *dimmingViewSubviews in windowSubView.subviews) {
>             for (UIView *popoverSubview in dimmingViewSubviews.subviews) {
>                 if([NSStringFromClass([popoverSubview class]) isEqualToString:@"UIView"]) {
>                     for (UIView *subviewA in popoverSubview.subviews) {
>                         if ([NSStringFromClass([subviewA class]) isEqualToString:@"UILayoutContainerView"]) {
>                             subviewA.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
>                         }
>
>                         for (UIView *subviewB in subviewA.subviews) {
>                             if ([NSStringFromClass([subviewB class]) isEqualToString:@"UIImageView"] ) {
>                                 [subviewB removeFromSuperview];
>                             }
>                             if ([NSStringFromClass([subviewB class]) isEqualToString:@"UILayoutContainerView"] ) {
>                                 for (UIView *subviewC in subviewB.subviews) {
>                                     if ([NSStringFromClass([subviewC class]) isEqualToString:@"UIImageView"]) {
>                                         [subviewC removeFromSuperview];
>                                     }
>                                 }
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library https://github.com/ddebin/DDPopoverBackgroundView

```
UIPopoverController *popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];
[popOver setPopoverBackgroundViewClass:[DDPopoverBackgroundView class]];
```

just set

```
[popOver.popoverBackgroundViewClass setContentInset:0.0f];
```

thats it.
But remember this will only work on **iOS 5+**